# how to create a cron job that runs on the first day of month

Tags: cron

There are fields on my server's control panel like this

Minute -  Hour -  Day of month - Month - Day of the week - Command

How can I create a cron job runs on first day of the month with this fields?

Comment: Just make a note for myself here: 0 0 1 * ? * [command]

Comment: It is very poor form to close a non-duplicate question just because an answer may exist elsewhere. It is obviously not a duplicate.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This will run the command foo at 12:00AM on the first of every month

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/foo
```

This article describes the various fields, look to the bottom of the page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

To add this to your cron file, just use the command

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: that looks ok i guess

Comment: can i type * instead of 0 ?

Comment: If you typed * instead of the first zero it would run every minute of the first day of the month, if you typed * for the second zero it would run every hour on the first day of the month.  *'s for both would run every minute of every hour on that day.

Comment: According to that Wikipedia page, the third and fifth fields are treated as OR clauses of the run condition, and the right syntax should be `0 0 1 * ?` though my Vixie cron on Ubuntu 14 LTS refuses them

Comment: be careful when run `crontab -e` because it write the cron according to the current user than crontab command.

Comment: thanks, How if we want to add 5 minutes ?

Answer (score 20):

Will run /usr/bin/foo at 12:10am on the **first day of the month**.

```
10 0 1 * * /usr/bin/foo
```

Will run /usr/bin/foo at 3:10am on **every day**.

```
10 3 * * * /usr/bin/foo
```

See http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html

---

updated the crons, it was a copy paste error, thanks Joy Dutta!

Comment: 3:10am every day is `10 3 * * * /usr/bin/foo`
12:10am on first day of month is `10 * 1 * * /usr/bin/foo`

Comment: @Joy: No it's not; 10 * 1 * * is 10 past the hour, every hour, on the first day of the month.

Comment: According to that Wikipedia page, the third and fifth fields are treated as OR clauses of the run condition, and the right syntax should be `0 0 1 * ?`, though my Vixie cron on Ubuntu 14 LTS refuses them

Comment: The link does not seem to exist anymore

Comment: @030 link works for me.

Answer (score 15):

use following:

```
@monthly     /home/user/backup.sh
```

more information:

- `man 5 crontab` (files used to schedule the execution of programs)
- [crontab(5): tables for driving cron - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)

Answer (score 2):

Check for a directory on your server at `/etc/cron.monthly`. If the directory exists, odds are your system is set up to run any executables it finds in that folder on a monthly basis. Just drop your script (or symlink it) in `/etc/cron.monthly`. Also, make sure your script is executable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
0 0 1 * * command /directory/file.ext
```

Comment: what is that 'command' and the 1 is at the month of the year place!

Comment: you can do whatever you want with a cron, 99% of my usage has been: {TIMESTAMPS} {PHP_PATH} {FILE_PATH}

Comment: @Murali: No it's not.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: [Class: PHP Cron](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4140.html)

Comment: Note that this question was not about PHP